# How to address ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException without using try-catch?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was given a homework assignment to check if all the elements of an array are the same value. I return true if they are, otherwise I return false. I was instructed to return true if the array was empty. The following code works in all cases except when the array has no elements - a length of zero. How could I go about addressing this issue?

```
    public static boolean allSame (double[] list) {
        double sameReference = list[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list [i] != sameReference)
                return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Do a check first: `if(list.length == 0) { return true; }`

Comment: Put a special case at the beginning of the method: `if (list.length == 0) return true;`

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty check

```
public static boolean allSame (double[] list) {
    if (list.length() == 0){ 
       return true;//list empty so return true
    }
    double sameReference = list[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list [i] != sameReference)
            return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: For each loop would better. No need to handle special conditions.